# youtube livestream down after 2 hour using ffmpeg

Tags: memory, ffmpeg, cpu-usage, youtube

stuck here I don't know how I can make this livestream last for 24/7 
please tell me what I'm doing wrong here.
the script I'm using

```
#! /bin/bash
#
# Diffusion youtube avec ffmpeg

# Configurer youtube avec une résolution 720p. La vidéo n'est pas scalée.

VBR="2500k"                                    # Bitrate de la vidéo en sortie
FPS="30"                                       # FPS de la vidéo en sortie
QUAL="ultrafast"                                  # Preset de qualité FFMPEG
YOUTUBE_URL="rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2"  # URL de base RTMP youtube

FOLDER="video"                                    # Dossier source
KEY="youtube-key"                                     # Clé à récupérer sur l'event youtube

SOURCE=""
n=0
filter=""

for f in $FOLDER/*.mp4
do
  SOURCE="$SOURCE -i $f"
  filter="$filter [$n:v:0] [$n:a:0]"
  ((n++))
done

filter="$filter concat=n=$n:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]"

echo "ffmpeg $SOURCE -filter_complex '$filter'"

ffmpeg \
    -stream_loop -1 $SOURCE  -filter_complex "$filter" \
-map "[v]" -map "[a]" -deinterlace \
    -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset $QUAL -r $FPS -g $(($FPS * 2)) -b:v $VBR \
    -acodec libmp3lame -ar 44100 -threads 6 -qscale 3 -b:a 712000 -bufsize 512k \
    -f flv "$YOUTUBE_URL/$KEY"
```

and I'm using a VPS with 512MB ram and 2GB to run FFmpeg the CPU usage hit 100% while running the Livestream.
when I start the livestream on youtube the health status was green then after 30 min it turns red with this message "YouTube is not receiving enough video"
any help tips are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There are two aspects to this question:

- Your immediate problem: You only have **nearly** enough CPU horsepower for the conversion. This means, that your video always ever so slightly falls back in time, until all buffering is exhausted and YouTube shows the problem. You must either use more CPU or chose a less demanding encoder setting.
- FFmpeg and 24x7 streams: It turns out, that ffmpeg will stall if some internal counter or timer rolls over. This is at around 44 days and ffmpeg will not end (which would be curable via a loop) but just stall, i.e. sit there not producing any output. We solve this problem by giving only portions of ca. 1 day to FFmpeg and then run it in a loop, thus creating ca. one restart per day. YouTube's buffering will make that completely invisible to the end user

Comment: thanks for taking the time to reply to my issue. do you suggest any parameters to add to this command to lower CPU usage?

Comment: The easiest way to reduce CPU load would be to set the framerate to a lower value - `FPS=25` might do it and is perfectly acceptable (standard in Europe)

Comment: I changed the value to 25 but the CPU usage still high 104%

Comment: How many vCPUs do you have? With 2 a value of 104% could easily be already OK.